# Split string return multiple values with Regex in swift 4

Tags: ios, regex, swift, string, split

I want to create an extension function which will split a string to an array with a format.
Example:

- Source string:

  ```
  "1~1895|usd||A:123000|B:1234"
  ```
- Pattern should like this:

  ```
  "int~int|string||A:int|B:int|C:int"
  ```
- Should return

  ```
  [1, 1895, "usd", 123000, 1234, nil]
  ```

I am trying to split with regex but I don't know how to return multiple values.

Comment: @matt Thank for your comment, currently, I use components(separatedBy: "|") to convert source string to an array and pass index to get value. This very hard to reuse with other pattern and easy to cause crash. So I do some research with regex, but I don't have any idea to response multiple value with other type

Answer (score 0):

Actually this would be a good use case for a Scanner. Scan the first number, scan through the twiddle, scan the next number, scan through the pipe, scan the string up to the pipe, scan through the two pipes, scan through to the colon, scan the number, and so forth.

Comment: "twiddle"  - I like that, more fun than "tilde". :)

Comment: I have never heard of Scanner before, thank for your help. I will research about it now